# My MBP will no longer shut down or restart

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, shutdown, reboot

My Macbook Pro was purchased late 2013.  I now have OS X 10.9.5 (13F34).  All of my Apple drop down menu items have become dysfunctional. I consistently cannot shutdown or reboot.

What can I do?

Comment: when did you upgrade to the 10.9.5 and from where ?

Comment: I upgraded to 10.9.5 about a week ago, started noticing problems about 2 days later. I used the Apple drop down menu.

Comment: OK, there is a problem, there is no longer a 10.9.5 upgrade available from Apple, so where did you get it from? I would question that installation package.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Mavericks installation is messed up.

If you still have the original Mavericks Install package you can check it with Terminal.

Type MD5

(with space) and now drag the Mavericks installer to the terminal window.

The result should be 7c2152a1afac38d2d06651add2d24968

I would recommend following steps:

Try to restore it using the cmd-r.

Following this, try to log in as different user to eliminate user profile problems.

As next step start in Safe mode to eliminate some of the 3d party apps problems.

Resetting the PRAM/NVRAN (EFI) and the SMC would be good as well.

Finally run the Apple Hardware test to check for hardware problems.

Comment: Do I need to have a backup first?

Comment: sorry, I assumed that to be the automatic action :)

Comment: I am a novice to tinkering with MacBooks

Comment: yes,there is no longer a 10.9.5 upgrade available. Do I dare go higher?

Comment: With 2013 model, I would say yes, go get the Yosemite :) BUT you can try to repair the existing 10.9.5 using the build in Restore function (it is on your hard drive already.